# Javascript file not loading from ScriptManager

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ScriptManager on a Master page that loads all of my javascript files. However, I found that one of my files was getting too big, so I decided to break it up into separate files, grouped by functional concern. However, these files don't seem to get loaded. When I reference a function declared in the new javascript file, I get a null reference error.

Here's an example:
I have SignOff.js and SignOffTools.js. Both are in the same directory. SignOff.js is the original large file. SignOffTools.js is the new file.

I have the following lines in the Master page.

```
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Tabs/SignOff.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Tabs/SignOffTools.js" />
```

Everything in SignOff.js loads fine. But if I make any reference to a SignOffTools.js function in my ascx file, say in an onclick event, I get a null reference exception.

After further investigation with Firebug it looks like SignOffTools.js is not being loaded. But I have no idea why.

I'm at a complete loss. Removing the reference to the legacy SignOff.js prevents it's being loaded. But adding a reference to any new file does not result in their being loaded. I've added src references to the ascx (tab), aspx (page) and Master page levels without any effect. I've even embedded the javascript directly in the tab without any success. But as soon as I copy the javascript into the legacy SignOff.js file everything works. As I can see no logic to this behavior, I'm left to conclude that it is the work of some malevolent spirit. I suppose the next step is for me to ring my PC in garlic and drive a wooden stake through the motherboard.

Comment: Never once had to register scripts like this using ScriptManager - a manual reference in the head or where I need it had always sufficed - I wonder what the perceived benefits are...

Comment: I'm not sure. This is a legacy app and I'm trying to maintain consistency.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab to see if the file is loaded or not found? You probably also need to clear cache on the home page, then open the network tab and right click - open in new window the Signoff.js file and clear cache there as well. Then close your browser and try loading again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by a missing curly brace } in one of the files. This caused all files referenced after that point to have their code become unparseable. Unfortunately Visual Studio didn't alert me to the error. It was discovered by a friend of mine using Resharper.